# How to set data default in embedded document mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am working with embedded document and I have set the default data for this model schema but when I am trying to create a new document, collection returned empty array. How can I set a default collection when new document added in a model schema in mongoose?

My model schema definition:

```
const ActionSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  canEdit: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  canDelete: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  canMention: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  }
});

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  detail: String,
  author: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  action: [ActionSchema]
});
```

It should be auto added default data every time a new post is added like this:

```
{
  title: 'Happy New Year',
  detail: 'Happy New Year 2024',
  author: ObjectId(...),
  action: [
    {
       canEdit: true,
       canDelete: false,
       canMention: true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only specified type to be an array of `ActionSchema`, but why should it create the item in the array? If you want that, you need to specify default value for `action` field too:

```js
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  detail: { type: String },
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  action: { 
    type: [ActionSchema], 
    default: [
      {
        canEdit: true,
        canDelete: false,
        canMention: true
      }    
    ]
  }
});
```